# How can I pass environment variable in nginx conf?

Tags: environment-variables, amazon-ec2, nginx

I have nginx conf as

```
location /static/ {
                alias $HOME/code/python/vlists/vlists/static/;
        # if asset versioning is used
        if ($query_string) {
            expires max;
        }
    }
```

where in I want to pass my $HOME from environment, so I do this

```
$ sudo -E nginx
nginx: [emerg] unknown "home" variable
```

How do I make sure that `$HOME` replaces correctly in `nginx.conf`?

Comment: Nginx supports several variables given here http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#Variables , `$home` is probably not supported